# Connect to remote MySQL from CircleCI

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, circleci

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server (hosted via AWS RDS) from a CircleCI build to save some artifacts. I can connect to the server from my local so I know the credentials work (and I tried without any AWS credentials locally) however I'm always getting timeout errors.

In my application, I am using nodejs so using the mysql module and I first try:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'foo.bar.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  user: 'my-user',
  password: '1234',
});

connection.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('good');
  }
});
```

As I said, it always has an error. As a test, I also tried using the `mysql-client` cli like:

```
  mysql:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10-browsers
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Test MySQL
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install mysql-client
      - run: mysql -u my-user -h foo.bar.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p1234
```

This tried for 2 minutes but results in:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'foo.bar.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110 "Connection timed out")
Exited with code 1
```

Anyone know of a reason that the same things can run locally no problem but within CircleCI this fails?

Comment: Try getting a post-build SSH session, and connecting from there, using the standard `mysql` binary. I don't believe there are any outbound firewalled ports, except perhaps the usual port 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, AWS created a security group that was locked down to my personal IP address. This is why locally I could connect but anywhere else I could not. Editing the security group to allow from anywhere, my CircleCI tasks can now connect to the MySQL server.